# S3 Class Names: What's Allowed?

Tags: class, r

Are there any restrictions on the names of S3 classes?  For instance, are spaces allowed in the name?  I see that data frames have a class of "data.frame" not "data frame".  If there is not a formal restriction, are there potential problems with having spaces in the name?  I just don't run into anything other than the basic modes so I'm sure those of you with more experience will know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doesn't look there are many restrictions at all.  Check out this monstrosity:

```
`plot.44 !@#$%^&` <- function(x) {
     plot(rnorm(x), pch=16, col="red",
          main = "But why would you want to do this??")
}

dat <- 55
class(dat) <- "44 !@#$%^&"
plot(dat)
```

One reason **not** to put spaces into a class name is that it makes it a bit trickier to directly call methods for that class.

```
plot.44 !@#$%^&(100)   # This doesn't work 

`plot.44 !@#$%^&`(100) # You have to do this instead
```

Comment: Just guessing, but among other things, I suppose the monstrosity may not be all that portable depending upon the encoding (besides being a monstrosity).

Comment: I could imagine that being an issue with some characters.  Probably not the ones I included there, though, since (I just realized) they're all used in one way or another in base R!

Comment: Does anyone foresee a problem in the Rd files using \code{\link{two words}} when documenting a class?  Certainly, \code{\link{one.word}} works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Spaces are allowed:

```
test = 1
class( test ) = c( class( test ) , "My Class" )
```

Not sure about other restrictions or consequences of having special characters in class names.  Certainly having spaces/special characters in class names is not conventional (not just R, but other languages).  I suggest avoiding that.